# ping dns works but nslookup fails?

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualization, ping, nslookup

I have an issue with DNS in my current lab environment, this happened after a snapshot recovery on the DC image :

Following [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzZhJ.png) shows that i can ping google.com but nslookup google.com fails, i have never seen such behaviour before, how is it even possible ?

Also i am still able to ping google.com even after an ipconfig /flushdns

DC still has internet connectivity but all the joined servers lost internet connectivity. Joined servers can still reach and resolve DC name.

Any idea how i can start to fix this issue ?

Comment: `ping` is not an adequate tool to troubleshoot DNS problems. `dig` is. On a given OS name resolution can happen in various ways, and DNS is just one source among others. Any application, `ping` or anything else, asks the OS to resolve the name for it. Depending on how the OS is configured it might not even use the DNS to do that. While on the other hand, `nslookup` being a DNS client does only DNS queries.

Comment: Please do not attach screenshots to your question, put the relevant information as textual data directly in the text. Both `ping` and `nslookup` are command line utilities, hence purely textual, so you can copy and paste any command and results as text in your question.

Comment: So `nslookup` thinks you have a DNS server/resolver running on your PC. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

What happened here is the following:

- `ping` asked the OS to resolve `google.com`, and the OS decided that it's going to return the IPv4 address to `ping`, probably because its IPv6 connection wasn't working.
- `nslookup` on the other hand defaulted to doing an lookup over IPv6, which by the look of things probably isn't configured correctly, hence no reply.

If you'd like to resolve this, either fix the IPv6 connection the machine has, or disable IPv6 on the active NIC.